# "To prevent possible data loss before loading the designer, the following errors must be resolved" when creating new Project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, project, clr

I just started with C++ after 2 years of experience with C#, and after making a couple of console applications I decided to make a windows forms application. I added the CLI component but when I go and create an empty clr and add a new form. it gives me this error:

> To prevent possible data loss before loading the designer, the following errors must be resolved

I looked around but couldn't find any solution so I decided to ask on here. It just simply doesn't load the designer. When I click on show call stack this is what I get:

```
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Designer.Interfaces.IVSMDCodeDomProvider.get_CodeDomProvider()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.CodeDomDocDataAdapter.get_Provider()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.CodeDomDocDataAdapter.get_CompileUnit()
at Micosoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.DeferredLoadHandler.Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsTextBufferDataEvents.OnLoadCompleted(Int32 fReload)
```